# how customize is_valid to accept empty chars

Tags: django, forms, validation

I try to sign_up User, and I want get possibility to name User with empty chars example "Mr Somebody" but method is_valid not pass my form. How can I modify method is_valid to take empty chars in User name?

```
def sign_up(request):
context = {}
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return render(request, 'accounts/index.html')
context['form'] = form
return render(request,'registration/sign_up.html', context)
```

Comment: This is not the `is_valid` method, this is blocked at the model level. Django has a `UnicodeUsernameValidator` (https://github.com/django/django/blob/d8dfff2ab0edf7a1ca5255eccf45c447b2f9d57e/django/contrib/auth/validators.py#L18-L25) that does not allow spaces, which is added as validator to the `username` field: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L335.

Comment: Sow If I overide regex expression adding \s in UnicodeUsernameValidator and set it in User it should be done case? https://pastebin.com/HqpkDjvi